# Internal Server Error when trying to change upload file size parameters in htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have edited a live WordPress site locally and am about to upload it to the live server. When doing this, I usually change (increase) the maximum file upload size since I am using a plugin to Export/Import the website, and this plugin only takes 100 MB of import file size (plugin: All in One WP Migration, free version).

When achieving this I add this code to the end of the .htaccess file located in the html folder:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size 1000M
php_value memory_limit 1000M
php_value max_execution_time 0
php_value max_input_time 300
```

This typically works well, but this time this error message is shown in the browser (on page refresh):

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

1. I have *stripped* the .htaccess file of code that is related to (and dynamically generated by) the Breeze cache plugin, and the site works as expected without this code (given that I have not added the "upload file size code" in the file).
2. I have *commented out* the code related to GD-SSL (Godaddy SSL), and the site works as expected without this code (given that I have not added the "upload file size code" in the file). For reference, please see file content below.

This is what my .htaccess file looks like after these edits (edits made in order to solve the error, of course):

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Options +FollowSymLinks
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^alloptik\.se$ [OR]
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^49l\.fd7\.myftpupload\.com$
# RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
# Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests"
# </IfModule>
# END GD-SSL

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size 1000M
php_value memory_limit 1000M
php_value max_execution_time 0
php_value max_input_time 300
```

Comment: _"More information about this error may be available in the server error log."_ - have you checked ...?

Comment: Hi,
Thanks, now I have... In the end of the log this error appears multiple times, but it is generated about an hour before my latest edits (and thus error messages):

[27-Sep-2022 08:59:33 UTC] objectcache.debug: Flushing object cache... shutdown_action_hook, do_action('shutdown'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WPaaS\Cache::ban, WPaaS\Cache::request, wp_cache_flush, apply_filters('pre_objectcache_flush'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, RedisCachePro\Plugin->maybeLogFlush

Comment: Then you are not looking in the correct error log.  Every time you refresh the page and get a 500 error, a new line is added to the live error log.  Without seeing this information, this question is nearly impossible to answer.

Comment: Thanks. I realize that. If it is not the "debug.log" file in the "wp-content" folder, which is the correct error log file and where is it most likely located?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Answer (score 3):

You can only use `php_value` (and related) directives in `.htaccess` if PHP is installed as an Apache *module*, which is probably not the case in your live server environment. The 500 Internal Server Error is likely due to the directive simply not being recognised.

You can try using a [per-directory `.user.ini` file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) instead (on CGI/FastCGI) containing:

```
; Custom settings
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
post_max_size = 1000M
memory_limit = 1000M
max_execution_time = 0
max_input_time = 300
```

However, you'll also need to check the `user_ini.filename` and `user_ini.cache_ttl` PHP INI settings as the expected filename might be different on your server and this file is "cached" by default.

Also, your host (GoDaddy) might impose additional restrictions (on *shared hosting plans*) that cannot be circumvented.

Reference:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Answer (score 1):

Please use like below into wp-config.php file and remove your htaccess php_value. follow screenshoot below.

https://prnt.sc/7xitGHbSIFEn

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '1000M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '1000M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

Comment: Thanks. Already tried this, but unfortunately the 100 MB limit is not changed which I find strange. However, the error message is not present.

Comment: you can use Increase Maximum Upload File Size plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-max-file-size/

Comment: Thanks. I am curious as to why this error occurs, and would prefer a solution without involving a plugin. A plugin would be the least favorable option mainly because I think it may compromise system stability.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think that the given code resolves the problem? Also, why did you suppress errors?